# Prove a norm in a $l^{finite}$ vector space

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

Consider $l^{finite}$ finite (the vector space of infinite sequences $f = (f_1, f_2, f_3,...)$
that have finitely many nonzero entries). On this space the 1-norm defined as
$$||f||_1 := \sum_{i=1}^\infty |f_i| $$
Prove $||f||_1$ is a norm.

I am starting and I struggle with proving that $||f||_1$ is convergent. Because the sum is too the infinity, so how can I show that it converges? Thank you.

Comment: Your sum only has finitely many nonzero terms so it converges.

Comment: I think I struggle to understand the definition of $f$. I mean if it is the sum of infinitely many sequences, how can it converge? I get that the sequences have finitely many nonzero entries, so they converge. But then the sum is of infinitely many sequences right...?

Comment: Consider, for instance, the series $\sum_{i=1}^\infty 0 = 0.$ There are infinitely many terms in the sum, but it still converges to a finite value (which in this case is $0$.)